# Spring Data MongoDB @Transactional failure

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions, mongo-java-driver

Could someone please tell me why this spring transaction is not rolling back appropriately?

**The error I get is this:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available
```

**This is my repository with a save transaction that will intentionally fail:**

```
@Repository
public class TransactionalRepository {

    private final PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionalRepository(PlayerRepository playerRepository) {
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    public Player saveSuccess(Player player) {
        return playerRepository.save(player);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Player saveFail(Player player) {
        player.setName("FAIL"); // should not be saved in DB if transaction rollback is successful
        player = playerRepository.save(player);
        throw new IllegalStateException("intentionally fail transaction");
    }
}
```

**And here is the test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MongoTransactionApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    public TransactionalRepository playerRepository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        Player player = new Player();
        player.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        final String PLAYER_NAME = "new-"+player.getId().subSequence(0,8);
        player.setName(PLAYER_NAME);
        player = playerRepository.saveSuccess(player);

        try {
            player = playerRepository.saveFail(player);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // this is supposed to fail
        }

        Assert.assertEquals(PLAYER_NAME, player.getName());
    }

}
```

[Download all the code here if you want to see it run](https://github.com/DinkoTontchev/mongo-transaction)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike other implementations the Spring Data MongoDB module does not by default register a `PlatformTransactionManager` if none is present. This is up to the users configuration, to avoid errors with non MongoDB 4.x servers as well as projects already using `@Transactional` along with a non MongoDB specific transaction manager implementation. Please refer to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.RC2/reference/html/#mongo.transactions) for details.

Just add a `MongoTransactionManager` to your configuration.

```
@Bean
MongoTransactionManager txManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

You might also want to check out the [Spring Data Examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples) and have a look at the one for [MongoDB transactions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/transactions).

Comment: Thank you for the help @Cristoph! i had to upgrade to spring boot "2.1.0.M3" in order to find "MongoTransactionManager". I updated my config as you suggested and but now my mongo environment needs to be replicated (apparently a requirement for transactions) before i can test it. I don't have the time to do that at the moment but once i verify working i can come back and accept your answer. For now i wanted to post this update for others.

Comment: Hey, I can't figure out how to make it work, I keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/ClientSession and similar errors.  
My setup is 

I added  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
  , 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Lovelace-RELEASE'
  , ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.1.0.RELEASE'  dependencies

Comment: @Ben which driver version do you have? Please make sure to use at least `mongodb-java-driver 3.8.0` respectively `mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams 1.9.0` or higher.